# Add values and legend to chart from excel

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I've built a chart on the values of their Excel Worksbook. And then save the picture.

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
// Diagram 2
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B12", "B15");

chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DPieExploded;
foreach (Series series in chartPage.SeriesCollection())
{
    series.Name = "Уровень удовлетворенности респондентов длительностью ожидания";
}

// export chart as picture file
String destPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
chartPage.Export(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dig2.bmp", "BMP", misValue);
```

How can I add a legend and values to the chart?